# ASP.NET ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem Common.Logging to NLog crashes IIS - Bug or just me?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, crash, nlog

I have a long-running asynchronous task that is kicked off from an ASP.NET MVC4 web page.  The controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            model.NotificationRecipient = model.NotificationRecipient.Replace(';', ',');
            ImportConfiguration config = new ImportConfiguration()
            {
                BatchId = model.BatchId,
                ReportRecipients = model.NotificationRecipient.Split(',').Select(c => c.Trim())
            };
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(foo => LaunchFileImporter(config, this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context));
            if (model.RunExport) ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(foo => LaunchFileExporter());
            Log.InfoFormat("Queued the ImportProcessor to process invoices.  Send Notification: {0} Email Recipient: {1}",
                model.SendNotification, model.NotificationRecipient);
            TempData["message"] = "The import processor job has been started.";
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Failed to properly queue the invoice import job.", ex);
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    var dirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dir);
    model.Files = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.xml").OrderBy(x => x.Name.ToLower());

    return View(model);
}
```

My `LaunchFileImporter` method looks like this:

```
private void LaunchFileImporter(ImportConfiguration config, System.Web.HttpContext context)
{
    //the semaphore prevents concurrent running of this process, which can cause contention.
    Log.Trace(t => t("submitter semaphore: {0}", (exporter == null) ? "NULL" : "present."));
    submitter.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        Log.Trace(t => t("Context: {0}", context));
        using (var processor = new ImportProcessor(context))
        {
            processor.OnFileProcessed += new InvoiceFileProcessing(InvoiceFileProcessingHandler);
            processor.OnInvoiceProcessed += new InvoiceSubmitted(InvoiceSubmittedHandler);
            processor.Execute(config);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Failed in execution of the File Importer.", ex);
    }
    submitter.Release();
}
```

My Logger is a Common.Logging `private static readonly ILog`, and is configured for NLog.  It seems properly wired up; at least, I get a fair amount of logs out of it.

Here's the thing:  The moment I hit `System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, the application pool death spirals into a silent death, resetting the app pool, reloading the membership provider, reprocessing the web.config, the whole shebang... No YSOD, no indication on the web page... everything just quietly blows up.  The last log entry I get is `Queued the ImportProcessor to process invoices...`.

I should note the page does the refresh.  The `TempData["message"]` is populated and displayed on the screen, which makes me believe the problem is happening in the asynchronous process... but pretty much immediately.  Due to the lack of additional logs I am assuming there is a problem with the logger.

So I'm hoping someone can either tell me what is happening, point to some documented issue with this, tell me how I'm being an idiot, or reproduce something similar as a bug.

Thanks!

***UPDATE***

@RichardDeeming pointed out that the context information was not getting into the spawned thread, and this seemed to be the cause of the problem.  I still haven't wrapped my brain around why this didn't work nor did it write the trace messages, but once I captured the part of the context that I needed, the `IPrincipal`, and used that instead of the context object, it just worked.

Comment: long-running async task and ASP.NET is a really bad combination...

Comment: Meh... I generally agree.  In this case there were circumstances that made this the best option available.

Comment: using additional background threads in IIS can impact IIS performance... another point is that IIS can reload your appdomain anytime (there are some config options) due to any reason (like memory pressure etc.). IF your appdomain is under heavy load the above might just be a symptom of a "hard reload" from IIS...

Comment: You might be getting a `NullReferenceException` on the line `foo => LaunchFileImporter(config, this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context)` - I'm pretty sure the `Context` gets cleaned up after the request has been completed. And as we know, an unhandled exception on a background thread brings down the whole `AppDomain`.

Comment: This application is used by exactly one person at any time.  It's really just a "button to push" for our A/P department in their office on the other side of the country to kick off what used to be a highly manual process once a day, so I'm confident that the server is not under high load.  I really think the telling point here is that the trace logs are not recorded in the log file, which start before the process even executes.

Comment: @RichardDeeming, I had heard about that, but I thought passing it through as an argument would preserve its values.  If not, is there a commonly used workaround?  I would still think I'd see the trace entries show up in the log before giving up the ghost.  Also, I don't see how it could be an unhandled exception unless the issue was actually with the logging.  Everything else is wrapped in a `try...catch` block.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Although you're passing it as an argument to the `LaunchFileImporter` method, you're doing that from a background thread. You could try capturing the `HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context` in the controller method and passing the captured instance across, but most of the `HttpContext` properties and methods won't work once the request has completed.

Comment: @RichardDeeming, that seems to be the answer.  I captured the `IPrincipal` out of the context (that was all I needed, I was being lazy) and adjusted the app to accept that, and it just started working.  If you make it into an answer, I'll accept it with thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get a `NullReferenceException` in the line:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(foo => LaunchFileImporter(config, HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context));
```

The `HttpContext` gets cleaned up once the request has completed. Since the exception is thrown on a background thread, it will bring down the whole `AppDomain`, causing your application to restart.

You need to capture the relevant state from the context in the controller action, and use that state in the `WaitCallback` delegate:

```
IPrincipal user = Context.User;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(foo => LaunchFileImporter(config, user));

// Or:
// ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => LaunchFileImporter(config, (IPrincipal)state);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I wish the symptoms weren't so durn mysterious.